# jQuery Isotope center expanded element

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, centering

I am using Isotope to layout a grid of blocks using the 'masonryHorizontal' layout mode. On click the selected box expands and re-adjusts the layout. What I want is to scroll the window so the expanded box is centered in the window horizontally. I have this working so that it scrolls to the expanded box, but it's not centered horizontally.

In my click function, I have the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
var itemPosition = $this.parent().data('isotope-item-position');
    $('#page').scrollTo({ top:itemPosition.y, left:itemPosition.x}, 500);
}, 800);
```

I know I have to adjust the itemPosition.x, but can't seem to calculate the correct center. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Here is a screenshot to reference
[image]

Need to center the expanded block

Comment: maybe you use css to make $('#page') center, and just scrollTo({ top:itemPosition.y}).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't think CSS alone will take care of this.

Comment: last night, i thinks your website just scroll up and down, but it seems not like that. Can you make a fiddle?